# Função buscar texto

Tags: javascript, html

Qual a forma correta para buscar texto na página?

Estou desenvolvendo uma "única" pagina em `HTML` e gostaria de um campo de busca ao digitar encontrar o texto, semelhante ao que acontece hoje com o `CTRL+F`, gostaria de manipular o campo encontrado com [css](/questions/tagged/css).

Comment: Não entendi a parte do html puro, está buscando uma solução usando somente html?

Comment: É só para entender onde estou programando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apenas com HTML não dá. O HTML apenas renderiza componentes no navegador.

Se topar usar ao menos JavaScript, [essa pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011385/jquery-search-in-static-html-page-with-highlighting-of-found-word) no S.O. ingles faz o que vc precisa.

[JQuery search in static HTML page with highlighting of found word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10011385/jquery-search-in-static-html-page-with-highlighting-of-found-word).

Comment: Sim irei implementar outras linguagens porem surgiu esse impasse no momento assim que eu chegar em casa irei analisar desde já obrigado pela resposta.